# setText from a parsed JSON object with AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpclient

Im making an android program that parses JSON texts from a source code of a webpage in the internet. It is working in android 2.2 but I need it now to be on android 3.0, which needs to be on the AsyncTask. I have a background about AsyncTask but I'm so confused where to put this and that. Thanks in advance everyone :)

Here is my method in the MainActivity class:

```
private void jsonStuffs() {
    //JSON PARSER & HOME PAGE TEXTVIEWS

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
        String returned;
        try {
            returned = test.getInternetData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            String jsonStr = test.getInternetData(); //go to GetMethodEx
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

//////////////////////find temperature in the JSON in the webpage

                String temperature = obj.getString("temperature");
                TextView tvTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tvTemp.setText(temperature);

        }
        //catch (JSONException e) {
             // e.printStackTrace();
            //} 
        catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

The GetMethodEx class is this (this will find the link of the webpage then convert it's source code to text format):

```
public class GetMethodEx extends Activity {
    public String getInternetData() throws Exception{

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        //

        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://nhjkv.comuf.com/json_only.php");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }finally {
            if (in !=null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` right?

Comment: google it before you ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (this code is just for illustration, change it as needed)

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
     protected void onPreExecute() {
        // You can set your activity to show busy indicator
        //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
     }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        return jsonStuffs();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject jsonObj) {
        String temperature = jsonObj.getString("temperature");
        TextView tvTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tvTemp.setText(temperature);
        // Stop busy indicator
        //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
```

To call this task use `new MyAsyncTask().execute();` (you can pass `String` parameters to execute if needed)
You can change your `jsonStuffs()` to return `JSONObject`

e.g.

```
private JSONObject jsonStuffs() {

     // ...

     String jsonStr = test.getInternetData(); //go to GetMethodEx
     return new JSONObject(jsonStr);

     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It is working in android 2.2 but I need it now to be on android 3.0,
>   which needs to be on the AsyncTask.

=> Yes it gives [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) in 3.0 if you make web call without implementing inside Thread such as AsyncTask.

> I have a background about AsyncTask but I'm so confused where to put
>   this and that.

=> Simply include web call logic inside `doInBackground()` method of the AsyncTask, in your case call getInternetData() inside `doInBackground()`.

FYI, you can't update UI straight way while doing long running task inside the doInBackground(). Yes if you want to update UI then do follow any of the below:

1. Update UI from the onPostExecute() method.
2. or implement `runOnUiThread()` inside the `doInBackround()`